# Installing Adaptec 5405 RAID card HDD LED

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, intel, adaptec

I'm trying to install an Adaptec 5405 RAID card into an Intel 1RU server, and I need to figure out how to connect the existing **SGPIO** connector from the backplane, onto the card itself (at least I assume that's how it should work).

## Details

The motherboard of the server is an Intel S3420GPLC board. I've already plugged the Adaptec card into the backplane connectors for each HDD, but I'm struggling to figure out how to connect the HDD LEDs up.

I can see the backplane has an **SGPIO** 4-pin connector which I believe is being used to communicate with the built-in storage controller on the motherboard (which is not needed anymore), as it connects to an **SGPIO** connector on the board.

From what I've read, the Adaptec 5405 supports for **SGPIO** and **I2C**, and has pins for the LED connection on the card. So it should simply be a matter of connecting the **SGPIO** connector in the correct fashion.

Can someone advise how I should be plugging this cable into the card? I'm worried about damaging the card and/or board if I do it incorrectly.

Some supporting information below.

- Document stating that the 5405 supports SGPIO (page 21): http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/user_guides/adaptec_raid_controller_iug_12_2011.pdf
- Document showing the LED pinout on the Adaptec card (page 114): http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/user_guides/adaptec_raid_controller_iug_4_2010.pdf
- Document showing the SGPIO pinout on the Intel server board (page 79): http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/s3420gp/sb/s3420gp_tps_r2_4.pdf
- Document illustrating the SGPIO connector and cable I am using, that came with the board/chassis (page 2): http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/ta_0946_01.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adaptec card supports SGPIO connections through SAS SFF-8087 connectors.

You cannot use LED connector for connecting to SGPIO on the backplane - first one just blinks directly connected LED's and second one is digital serial interface.

You need to buy SFF-8087 or similar cable with SGPIO connector, then connect required pins from standard SGPIO connectors to the socket on the Intel backplane.

This is standard cable:

[image]

This is intel pinout on board:

[image]

This is standard pinout:

[image]

You need to connect **clock to clock**, **load to load**, **data in to data out** (connecting data in to data in and data out to data out won't break anything, it just won't work).
It's easy to guess which one is what on the cable, just use tester to find out GND's, but before you'll need proper SFF-8087-aware cable. You must solder it in secure way.

Note: I use Adaptec cards on my servers, despite SGPIO standard, backplanes and adapters are not always 100% compatible with each-other.

Comment: I'll update answer with exact pinout for both

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead with the array build anyway (since I can always swap out cables later) and it seems like the HDD LEDs on each bay are actually working... Despite the fact the SGPIO cable is connected to the MB and not the card, I could have sworn this didn't work previously. Maybe they're not working entirely correctly?

Comment: But thanks for confirming that I had reached a dead-end without the appropriate cable. It did come with a break-out cable, with an LED connector, but I don't think it's SGPIO, from memory it had about 12 pins (or maybe 10), but not 4 and so I couldn't connect with it either. So that blue cable you've pictured looks like exactly what I need!

Comment: you're welcome. see updated answer